# How to loop through various workbooks to copy specific cells into another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have four Excel workbooks: `JAN18`, `FEB18`, `MAR18` and `manWrkbk` in the same folder.

I want to loop to get values from the same cells: `D46`, `E15` and `B12`, respectively, from workbooks `JAN18`, `FEB18`, and `MAR18` and display it in `manWrkbk` one after another, as shown below.

How can I accomplish this with VBA code?

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Improved formatting, tagging and re-phrased question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CopyWb()
Dim Filename As String, path As String
path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"
Filename = Dir(path)

Do Until Filename = ""
If Filename = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
GoTo Last1
End If
Workbooks.Open path & Filename
Cells(46, 4).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Last1:
Filename = Dir()
Loop

path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"
Filename = Dir(path)

Do Until Filename = ""
If Filename = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
GoTo Last2
End If
Workbooks.Open path & Filename
Cells(15, 5).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Last2:
Filename = Dir()
Loop

path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"
Filename = Dir(path)

Do Until Filename = ""
If Filename = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
GoTo Last3
End If
Workbooks.Open path & Filename
Cells(12, 2).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Filename
Last3:
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```